# How to specify a directory to tangle all code blocks into

Tags: org-mode, tangle

I am writing a report in latex, many of which contain code blocks which will be rendered with asymptote.

Since all the scripts will be tangled into the same subdirectory `asyscripts`, I don't want to have to write code like
this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC asy :tangle asyscripts/test.asy
write("Hello World!");
#+END_SRC
```

Specifying `asyscripts` every time is just too tedious. Any way I can specify globally which directory all the code blocks must be tangled into? (Each code block will be in general tangled into a different script.
)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any header args to do this (I thought that `:dir` would be the one, but it does not make any difference in tangling). But you can use the post-tangle hook, `org-babel-post-tangle-hook`, to manipulate the tangled files after they are produced. Here is a test file:

```el
#+PROPERTY: dest ./tangled/

* Link

* TODO foo

#+BEGIN_SRC asy :tangle test.asy
write("Hello World!");
#+END_SRC


#+BEGIN_SRC asy :tangle test2.asy
write("Good-bye World!");
#+END_SRC


* Code                                                                                                        :noexport:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (setq ndk/tangle-dir (org-entry-get nil "dest" t))

  (defun ndk/org-babel-tangle-rename ()
    (let ((tangledir ndk/tangle-dir)
          (tanglefile (buffer-file-name)))
        (rename-file tanglefile tangledir t)))

  (add-hook 'org-babel-post-tangle-hook #'ndk/org-babel-tangle-rename)
#+end_src
```

The code consists of three things:

- the setting of a global variable `ndk/tangle-dir` to the directory path where you want the tangled files to end up. You could hardwire this into the function, but I made it a bit more flexible by defining a global `#+PROPERTY` called `dest` whose value is the path (N.B. The path *MUST* end with a slash). We retrieve the value of the `dest` property with `org-entry-get` and set `ndk/tangle-dir` to that value.
- a function that will be called through the hook on every file that is tangled. The function is run in a buffer that contains the tangled output. We retrieve the file name from the buffer, and then we call `rename-file` to move that file to the destination directory. The `t` argument means it's OK to move it there even if a file with the same name exists in that directory already.
- adding the function above to the `org-babel-post-tangle-hook`.

If you create an Org mode file with the contents above, and create the destination directory, you should be able to open the Org mode file, `C-c C-c` on the source code block, `C-c C-v C-t` to tangle the two blocks in the `foo` section and then check out the contents of the destination directory: the two tangled files should be there.

You probably want to remove the function from the hook afterwards, otherwise all files you tangle will end up in that directory:

```el
(remove-hook 'org-babel-post-tangle-hook #'ndk/org-babel-tangle-rename)
```

For another example of the use of this hook, see [this recent question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61108/make-tangle-dont-add-a-newline-at-the-end-of-the-file/61113#61113). As you can see, it's pretty flexible!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding in this Header property at the top of your org file? This is what I add to most of my org files that I want tangled to a specific directory.

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:emacs-lisp :noweb yes :tangle emacs.d/init.el
```

just replace the emacs.d/init.el with the location of where you want your tangle files to be located. You can drop the ":emacs-lisp" and the ":noweb yes" if you don't need them.
So to just recap, you can try just adding this to the top of your file:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args  :tangle "asyscripts/test.asy"
```

and it should tangle your source blocks to that location.
(I'm using emacs 25.3.1 and Org mode version 9.2.3 (9.2.3-13-g727c3f-elpa if that helps, I've been using this tag back from org mode version 9.1.10)

Comment: They are to be tangled to the same subdirectory, but (as I read the question) *NOT* to the same file.

Comment: AFAICS, specifying a subdirectory in the argument of `:tangle` doesn't have any effect.