# Specifying a subdirectory in the argument of :tangle: effect only non-interactively

Tags: org-mode, directories, tangle, batch-mode

Recently, I added to this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61383/5267) to the question “How to specify a directory to tangle all code blocks into”,  the following comment: “AFAICS, specifying a subdirectory in the argument of :tangle doesn't have any effect”.

At least that is what I see with the following property:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :padline no :mkdirp yes :tangle my/sub/directory/myfile.foo :exports both :noweb yes :eval always
```

and tangling triggered with `org-babel-tangle` (`C-c C-v t`), the file `myfile.foo` is created in the current directory and not in the subdirectory `my/sub/directory/`.

But I discovered that if the tangling is run non-interactively (in batch mode, outside of `Emacs`) with the command:

```
emacs -Q letgut.org --batch -f org-babel-tangle --kill
```

then the file `myfile.foo` is, as expected, created in the subdirectory `my/sub/directory/`.

Do you understand the reason for the difference between these two ways of tangling and how to make `org-babel-tangle` behave like the command above?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: interactively tangling the file creates the subdirectory `my/sub/directorory` and creates the file `myfile.foo` in that subdirectory. Check what `default-directory` is (with `C-h v default-directory`), make sure that you can create the subdirectory in that directory (`mkdir -p my/sub/directory` from the shell - you can delete it afterwards to try again). Also, the `#+PROPERTY:` keyword line needs to be active: if you just added it, make sure you do `C-c C-c` on it to activate it; or close the file and reopen it.

Comment: BTW, you can do `M-x org-babel-view-src-block-info` on a source block to see e.g. whether the `header-args` property is set to what you think it is set.

Comment: Did you `C-c C-c` on the `#+PROPERTY` line to activate it? Or close and re-open the file? It seems to work. I suggest removing your comment on the other answer.

Comment: @NickD (and @mankoff) You're right: the `#+PROPERTY:` keyword line wasn't active. Strangely, `C-c C-c` on it has the effect to change the mode from Org to LaTeX (AUCTeX). You can make you comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There is something really strange about your setup: this should not happend at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These are my original comments made into an answer -- but note that there is a mysterious mode change that is so far unexplained.]

I cannot reproduce the problem: interactively tangling the file creates the subdirectory `my/sub/directorory` and creates the file `myfile.foo` in that subdirectory.

Check what the value of `default-directory` is (with `C-h v default-directory`), make sure that you can create the subdirectory in that directory (mkdir -p my/sub/directory from the shell - you can delete it afterwards to try again) - this should catch e.g. bad permissions that don't let you create the subdirectories or the file.

Also, the `#+PROPERTY:` keyword line needs to be active: if you just added it, make sure you do `C-c C-c` on it to activate it; or close the file and reopen it.

You can do `M-x org-babel-view-src-block-info` on a source block to see e.g. whether the `header-args` property is set to what you think it is set.

---

The OP reports that the `header-args` property was not set. But doing `C-c C-c` on it to activate it, changes the major mode of the file from Org to LaTeX. It's not at all clear why that happens: I'm surmising setup problems, but I have no data to even theorize how that could happen. Presumably, closing and reopening the Org file also resolves the problem and does not cause the mode change - but only the OP knows for sure at this point.

Comment: About the change of the major mode from Org to LaTeX, I have asked a [new question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71867/5267).