# Within an org file, is there any difference between mark-page and mark-whole-buffer?

Tags: page

According to Emacs documentation:

```
mark-whole-buffer
```

> Documentation: Put point at beginning and mark at end of buffer.

And:

```
mark-page
```

> Documentation: Put mark at end of page, point at beginning.

The definition of a [page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PageCommands):

> Pages of text are pages only when then are printed. Within Emacs, you
> can think of them more as sections of text. The sections are separated
> by page-break characters. The page-break character is also known as
> the “form feed” character, and it is the same as Control l (`^L’),
> octal 014.

I do not really understand: *when then are printed*.

While reading an `.org` file, is there any difference between `mark-page` and `mark-whole-buffer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any file, whether it's `org-mode` or not, whether there is a difference between `mark-page` and `mark-buffer` depends on whether or not you've inserted any page-break characters (i.e., `C-q C-l`). If you don't use page breaks, then there is no difference.

I've never used pages breaks in Emacs. Presumably they could be useful in `org-mode` if you wanted to divide the text in a way that didn't match up with the tree structure of nodes that org is designed around. If that's not useful to you, then you can ignore pages, and treat the page commands as synonyms for buffer commands.

Comment: One place where form feed characters can be useful is when you have a section that might look like a local file variables section but you don't want emacs to interpret it as such: emacs only looks for local file variables in the last "page" of the file. See e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71867/c-c-c-c-on-property-keyword-line-changes-the-mode-from-org-to-tex) and [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) of the Emacs manual.